# why doesn't parsed Double behave correctly?

Tags: java

I have a simple calculator here with a switch statement that should allow the user to enter a string like so:
*5

the operator can be - + / or * 
The code performs correctly during addition, however, when I subtract a value it adds it, and dividing or multiplying will result in the exceptions listed below.

```
Enter an operator and a number:
+5
Enter an operator and a number:
*2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "*2"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at Calculator.whatOperator(Calculator.java:38)
    at Calculator.aResult(Calculator.java:29)
    at Main.main(Main.java:30)
```

I believe I am not parsing the double correctly for some reason but am unsure how to do so...I was thinking stringtokenizer but how can I use the tokenizer without a delimiter?
Here is my calculator class and below that is my main class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator {
    private final int RESET = 0;
    private double number = 0;
    private double result = 0; 
    private char operator;
    private Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    public Calculator(double number)
    {
        this.number = number;

    }
    public void reset()
    {
        this.number = RESET;
    }
    public double aResult(Calculator other)
    {

        other.whatOperator();
        this.result = other.result;
        return result;

    } 

    public void whatOperator()
    {
        String operatorString = enterNumber();
        // the error occurs here....is there a better way to do this?
        double theNumber = Double.parseDouble(operatorString);
        char theOperator = operatorString.charAt(0);
        this.operator = theOperator;
        operatorString ="";
        operatorString += theOperator;

        // the switch should perform the operation 
        switch(operatorString){
        case "*":
        result = getNumber() * theNumber;
        break;
        case "/":
        result = getNumber() / theNumber;
        break;
        case "+":
        result = getNumber() + theNumber;
        break;
        case "-":
        result = getNumber() - theNumber;
        break;
        case "R":
        result = RESET;
        break;
        case "P":
        System.out.println("Goodbye");
        System.exit(0);

    }


}
public double add(double secondNumber)
{
    result = number + secondNumber;
    return result;

}
public double divide(double secondNumber)
{
    result = number / secondNumber;
    return result;
}
public double multiply(double secondNumber)
{
    result = number * secondNumber;
    return result;
}
public void subtract(double secondNumber)
{
    result = number - secondNumber;
}


public double getNumber()
{
    return number;
}
public void setNumber(double number)
{
    this.number = number;
}
    public  String enterNumber()
    {

        System.out.println("Enter an operator and a number:");
        String toString = keyboard.nextLine();
        return toString;
    }

}
public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Calculator a = new Calculator(0);
        a.setNumber(a.aResult(a));
        a.setNumber(a.aResult(a));
        String theString = String.valueOf(a.getNumber());
        System.out.println(theString);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you enter +/- 5 it takes it positive or negative 5 which is valid string but not able to evaluate *or/ to proper value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
double theNumber = Double.parseDouble(operatorString);
```

because it parses the operator as part of the number. Instead, use this:

```
double theNumber = Double.parseDouble(operatorString.substring(1));
```

Comment: such an easy fix! sometimes the easiest mistakes are the easiest to overlook. Will accept your answer when I can. Thanks